# error crash and Exit the application because i used library for zoom in and out and this library support sohw imaged from url by bitmap

Tags: list, android-recyclerview, zooming, bitmapimage

it's exit whent flip quickly from recyclerview
and the code i used is:

Glide.with(getApplicationContext())

```
.asBitmap()

.load(Uri.parse(list.get((int)(_position))))

.into(new CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {

    @Override

    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {

        imageview1.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(bitmap));

    }

    @Override

    public void onLoadCleared(Drawable placeholder) {

        

    }

});
```

i try another ways but ic cant fixed